# angular 4 - watch property of a variable for change

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to watch the nested property of a json. Whenever this nested property changes call a fn().

```
export class HeaderComponent  {
  user: any;

  constructor(){
    this.user = {
      options: [
        { name: 'Jenny Hess', img: 'assets/img/avatar/small/jenny.jpg' },
        { name: 'Elliot Fu', img: 'assets/img/avatar/small/elliot.jpg' },
        { name: 'Stevie Feliciano', img: 'assets/img/avatar/small/stevie.jpg' }
      ],
      selected: { name: 'Jenny Hess', img: 'assets/img/avatar/small/jenny.jpg' }
    }
  }
```

**Fn changes values**

```
public changeUser(item) {
    this.user.selected = item;
    /*Some Code here*/
}

  public customLogin(user) {
        /*Some Code here*/
        this.user.selected = user;
        /*Some Code here*/
}
```

Whenever the value of  `this.user.selected` changes call a function.
I'm using `rxjx` as well.

Any suggestion??

Comment: Is `HeaderComponent` needing to watch the value or another component (a parent component) ?

Comment: @ADreNaLiNe-DJ No. value of `this.user.selected` getting changed within `HeaderComponent` via a function.

Comment: Provide more information, in what way it will change. You can try with `ngDoCheck`.

Comment: Provide details like: how exactly is property being changed, where exactly do you want to observe that change?

Comment: @dee zg  @YordanNikolov  Edited the post adding `Fn changes values`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
export class HeaderComponent implements OnDestroy {
  user: any;
  userSelectSubject: BehaviorSubject<{name: string, img: string}>;
  private userSelectSubscription: Subscription;

  constructor(){
    this.user = {
      options: [
        { name: 'Jenny Hess', img: 'assets/img/avatar/small/jenny.jpg' },
        { name: 'Elliot Fu', img: 'assets/img/avatar/small/elliot.jpg' },
        { name: 'Stevie Feliciano', img: 'assets/img/avatar/small/stevie.jpg' }
      ]
    }

    this.userSelectSubject = new BehaviorSubject<{name: string, img: string}>({ name: 'Jenny Hess', img: 'assets/img/avatar/small/jenny.jpg' });

    this.userSelectSubscription = this.userSelectSubject.subscribe((newSelectedUser) => {
      this.user.selected = newSelectedUser;
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.userSelectSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Then you just need to call `this.userSelectSubject.next({...})` passing the new selected user as parameter.

Comment: Thanks @Giovane It helped

Comment: importing the Subscription but get error ".subscribe is not a function", anything i miss.?